# Win10 PC-1 only sees Win10 PC-2 under Network on certain circumstances

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-sharing

This is an odd one.

PC-2 is a PC where my family stores files on the C drive that is shared as a User share (C, not C$).

I used to be able to see PC-2 from PC-1 listed under "Network" just fine, by just opening a Windows Explorer window, going to Network and seeing it there. However, since this morning, it is not working. I can still open folders that are shared on PC-2 from PC-1 (through shortcuts, or just typing it on the Run dialog), however PC-2 is not listed under Network anymore.

Setup and known facts

- No password changed recently on either computer.
- Both computers are connected using ethernet.
- Using local accounts on both.
- I can ping PC-2 from PC-1 and vice versa just fine.
- Both PCs are on the same windows work group.
- Confirmed that Discovery is set to On on PC-2 for Private networks.
- Can still see all files, create new files and list contents on the shared folders on PC-2 from PC-1.
- When I open a PC-2 shared folder from PC-1 by double clicking it, PC-2 does show under Network on the left side Nav, but not on the main explorer area. Also very strange.

The reason why I need PC-2 to still be listed under Network is because I have a scanner on PC-1 that only allows the Save Location to be set to a remote computer if it shows under Network. The program does not let me type the location directly nor it allows me to specify shortcuts to other computers.

If it makes any difference, and is also odd, is that I cannot access the Default C$ share (from PC-1 into PC-2) even with the proper admin credentials from PC-2. I can even remote desktop to it, and I know the credentials are also good because I have logged off and on to PC-2 with those credentials.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if both the **Function Discovery Resource Publication**, and **Function Discovery Provider Host** services are enabled on both computers.  You can test by just setting both to "Start" on both computers and if that does the trick then set both services to start automatically on both computers.

Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services.